# LinearLayout (dynamically) withLayoutParams (int , int) get invisible

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

When I set layout params text checkbox go invisible. I'd Like This visible.
Thank Y

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(30, 60);
                        LinearLayout layoutCb = new LinearLayout(this);
                        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                        checkbox.setHeight(30);
                        checkbox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        int cbnum = coluna+1;
                        checkbox.setTag("CbCargaNotasL"+cbnum);
                        checkbox.setWidth(37);
                        checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
                        layoutCb.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        layoutCb.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                        layoutCb.addView(checkbox);
                        layoutCb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                        LinhaTabela.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        LinhaTabela.addView(layoutCb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your LayourParams with this..

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

check if this helps.

Comment: To get warp/warp. Don't need layout params its dafault. I wanna layout with size (30, 60);

Comment: Ok! first you tell me that how many child view in your LinhaTabela. And what is linhaTabela is it an another layout ?

Comment: LinhaTabela = Line of Table (Tablerow)